# How to pivot table correctly with tidyverse?

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, etl, data-wrangling

I´m using tidyverse to extract two different datasets from NOAA:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)

SOI <- read_table("https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/soi.data",
       skip = 1, 
       n_max = 74,
       col_names = FALSE) %>%
set_names(c('year', month.abb)) %>%
pivot_longer(-year, 
           names_to = 'month',
           values_to = 'SOI')

SOI <- SOI %>%
mutate(
year = substr(year, 0, 4), # Preserve only the fourth last digits
YearMonth = paste(year," ",month),
YearMonth = yearmonth(YearMonth)
     ) 

# SOI <- SOI %>%
# filter(SOI != -99.99)

SOI <- data.frame(SOI$YearMonth, SOI$SOI) %>%
rename(
 YearMonth = "SOI.YearMonth",
 SOI = "SOI.SOI"
 ) %>%
 as_tsibble()

 glimpse(SOI)
```

And the output is:

```
  Rows: 778
  Columns: 2
  $ YearMonth <mth> 1951 jan, 1951 fev, 1951 mar, 1951 abr, 1951 mai, 1951 jun, ~
  $ SOI       <dbl> 1.5, -0.2, -0.5, -1.1, 0.3, -1.7, -0.4, -1.8, -1.6, -1.3, -1~
```

In the same logic I tryed to do the same with ONI dataset:

```
ONI <- read_table("https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/oni.data",
       skip = 1, 
       n_max = 73,
       col_names = FALSE) %>%
set_names(c('year', month.abb)) %>%
pivot_longer(-year, 
           names_to = 'month',
           values_to = 'ONI')

 ONI <- as.data.frame(ONI)

 ONI <- ONI %>%
  mutate(
   year = substr(year, 0, 4) #, # Preserve only the fourth last digits
#YearMonth = paste(year," ",month),
#YearMonth = yearmonth(YearMonth) 
)        

ONI <- ONI %>%
  filter(ONI != -99.90)

glimpse(ONI)
```

And the result is:

```
Rows: 788
Columns: 3
$ year  <chr> "1950", "1950", "1950", "1950", "1950", "1950", "1950", "1950", ~
$ month <chr> "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "~
$ ONI   <dbl> -1.34, -1.16, -1.18, -1.07, -0.85, -0.54, -0.42, -0.39, -0.44, -~
```

By inspecting the first register (as expected to be Jan 1948 for SOI and Jan 1950 for ONI) I see that the wrong pivoted values are in my time series object.

The first value expected to be for Jan 1948 (in https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/soi.data) SOI was -99.99 and for ONI (https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/oni.data) have to -1.53 for Jan 1950.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Well for starters you are removing rows from SOI with values of `-99.9` with the line `filter(SOI != -99.99)` so you shouldn't expect to see those values in your `SOI` data frame.

Comment: The output is correct for me for `ONI` as well. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this line `substr(year, 0, 4)` because `year` is numeric and you're applying `substr` on it. Also the function `yearmonth` from is not from the `tidyverse` so your posted code errors on that line.

Comment: If I cannot use ``substr(year, 0,4)``  the values of the year column pick together the first column (the correct jan).  ``yearmonth`` function cames with fpp3 lib. Even using ``filter(SOI !=-99.99)`` the first line of the dataframe should be 2.50 and not 1.5.

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and based on this smaller example, please share also your expected output if you want to get proper help.